# Can't display custom menu using name?

Tags: menus

I want two menus using the new WordPress 3.0 feature.

In `functions.php` I have:

```
function register_my_menus() {
 register_nav_menus(
    array(
     'header-menu' => __( 'Header Menu' ),
     'top-menu' => __('Top Menu')
   )
 ); 
}

add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menus' );
```

And in `header.php` I have:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'name' => 'Header Menu' ) ); ?>
....
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'name' => 'Top Menu' ) ); ?>
```

Now they seem to fallback or something, always showing the same menu.
The menus have been defined and setup in wp-admin "theme-locations".

Why won't they load appropriately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`wp_nav_menu()` does not have a `name` argument](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu). Instead, you should use `theme_location`.

With [`register_nav_menus()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_nav_menus), you indicate that you have two locations in your theme where you can display a menu. The user can then create multiple menus, and assign them to these locations. This is why we have the indirection via `theme_location`. If you know the ID, slug or name of the menu you want to use, you can use the `menu` argument of `wp_nav_menu()`.